# SWIG generated TCL-wrappers with arbitrary number of arguments

Tags: c++, tcl, swig

I am using SWIG to generate wrapper code for calling C++ functions from TCL. My .i file  contains only the following:

```c++
%module baseFunc

%{
#include "tclFunctions.cpp"
%}

%include "tclFunctions.h"
```

The header file is essentially dozens of these declarations:

```
static signed int some_function(const char * argN=NULL); //Maybe more arguments
```

While all the C++ functions have fixed number of arguments, the calls from TCL must have a variable number of arguments. I would like to implement this behavior by converting the TCL call's list of arguments to a std::vector and pass that vector to the C++ function. This will be more compatible with the existing argument checking code inside many of the C++ functions.

I tried adding the following to my .h and .i files but it doesn't work since SWIG adds code to check the number of arguments on the TCL side.

```c++
//tclFunctions.h

static signed int some_function(const std::vector<std::string> args);
```

```c++
//baseFunc.i

%typemap(in) const std::vector<std::string> {
  Tcl_Obj **listobjv;
  int       nitems;
  int       i;
  if (Tcl_ListObjGetElements(interp, $input, &nitems, &listobjv) == TCL_ERROR){
     return TCL_ERROR;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < nitems; i++) {
     $1.push_back(Tcl_GetStringFromObj(listobjv[i],0));
  }
}
```

This is what checks the arguments in the resulting _wrap.c file

```c++
 if(SWIG_GetArgs(interp,objc,objv,"o:test_function args ",(void *)0)==TCL_ERROR)
   SWIG_fail;
```

How can I define a means so that whenever SWIG encounters `std::vector<std::string>` as a sole function argument, it accepts any number of TCL arguments and puts them all in a `std::vector`? Is SWIG not the correct tool to do this? The main hurdle I have here is that SWIG enforces argument counts and most of the commands take arbitrary arguments in any order.

The application cannot ask the user to do things like `$some_function {arg1 arg2 arg3}` because it **must** support commands like this.

```
#Only 2 args required but they can appear in any order.
report_timing -from [all_registers -clock_pins] \
  -to [all_registers -data_pins] -delay_type max \
  -path_type full_clock –nosplit \
  -max_paths 1 -nworst 1 \
  -trans -cap -net > tc_reg2reg_setup.rpt
```

Comment: I'd have thought that a `vector<string>` would be a natural fit for a Tcl list…

Comment: @DonalFellows What do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not in front of a computer at the moment to give you a verified working example, but the code you need to translate Tcl lists to vector looks something like:

```
%include <std_vector.i>
%include <std_string.i>
// instantiate template and give it a Pythonic name.
%template(vstr) std::vector<std::string>;
```

Then C++ functions like:

```
int some_function(const std::vector<std::string> args);
```

Can be called in Tcl with:

```
some_function {arg1 arg2 ... argN}
```

#### Edit

Sorry, guess I didn't read all the way to the end about the restriction.  Variable argument lists aren't really supported by SWIG, but you could write proxy functions in Tcl for the SWIG functions:

```
proc report_timing {args} {
        swigs_report_timing $args
}
```

This allows the variable arguments used by `report_timing` to be passed as a single list of arguments.

Comment: It's not what the questioner asked for, but it's what they get if they're going to use a vector of strings and it appears to be the _right way_ to do it. A simple Tcl wrapper could handle the rest of making things appear how they want (and that's going to be the easiest way to do it).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the right way? Passing a single list to represent multiple function arguments is inconsistent with TCL's own built-in commands and all the other EDA tools I use.

Comment: @Adam: But the user may never need to know that the "real" function cannot accept multiple arguments. Just write another function as a wrapper that *can* accept multiple arguments and formats those arguments correctly to call the "real" function.